# Django-taggit: how to search for all tags based on another column or foreign key?

Tags: django-taggit

The django-taggit example shows how to get all tags for one specific model, and I know there is a way to get all tags in the system, but how do I get all tags based on a foreign-key?

I have tags for the Event model, and there is a primary-key/foreign-key relationship between the EventOrganizer and Event. Each EventOrganizer will have different set of tags, and when he/she logs in, I only want to show the tags that this organizer is concerned about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Event model looks something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(EventOrganizer)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    # ...
```

You can filter tags by `event.organizer`:

```
from taggit.models import Tag
tags = Tag.objects.filter(event__organizer=organizer)
```